# problems with VBA code application or object error

Tags: vba, object, defined

I have coded some code in VBA my code breaks at this line raising Application defined or object defined error.

```
.Formula = "=IF(AND(chr(34) & ' & chr(34) & Criterion " & i & "'!" & cellAdress & ">=1;chr(34) & ' & chr(34) & Criterion " & i & "'!" & cellAdress & "<=4);chr(34) & ' & chr(34) & Criterion " & i & "'!" & cellAdress & ";0)"
```

I really tried to check what is wrong but it looks fine too me.  Please let me know what could be wrong and how to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: In the meantime, maybe you can go and check if you can accept some of the answers to your earlier questions? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
.Formula = "=IF(AND('Criterion " & i & "'!" & cellAdress & ">=1;'Criterion " & i & "'!" & cellAdress & "<=4);'Criterion " & i & "'!" & cellAdress & ";0)"
```

At least this produces a valid and sensible cell formula, your's does not.

With `cellAdress` set to `"A1"` and `i` set to `10`, the result would be:

```
"=IF(AND('Criterion 10'!A1>=1;'Criterion 10'!A1<=4);'Criterion 10'!A1;0)"
```

Comment: I tried this in the first place, however it produced same error someone advised me to add quotes:

=IF(and("'Criterion " & i & "'!" & cellAdress & ">=1;"'Criterion " & i & "'!" & cellAdress & "<=4);"'Criterion " & i & "'!" & cellAdress & ";0)

However my VB was adding a space between first " and ' making content after the latter appearing as a comment.  I tried to escape it using chr(34).  What could be wrong then?  I tried to check your code, but excel says that the formula contains an error.

thx

Comment: @niuchu: My VBA editor, where I just tested it, accepts this as legal code that produces exactly the string I show in the answer. And Excel accepts that string as a perfectly valid cell formula. You are doing something wrong. Hint: Maybe you should check what `cellAdress` and `i` contain in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understand it now.  My VBA also doesn't raise any errors until I run.  Maybe I'm looking on this code for too long and go crazy.  My cell Address contains D18 and i contains 1.  I do have a sheet called Criterion 1 and the cell in this sheet has a value of 2 (i also tried when it was empty).  Still this error is raised and I don't know what is causing it.